# Samba mount keeps timing out

Tags: mount, samba, fstab

I have several mounted drives to a windows share on an ubuntu server machine.

```
//WindowsFileServer/Media /mnt/Media cifs credentials=/home/drew/.smbcreds,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0

//WindowsFileServer/Media2 /mnt/Media2 cifs credentials=/home/drew/.smbcreds,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0

//WindowsFileServer/Plex\040Optimized /mnt/Optimized cifs credentials=/home/drew/.smbcreds,uid=108,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

After around 24 hours, I'll go to `/mnt` and run an `ls` command and the console hangs. The programs that try to access files in the mounted locations timeouts. A reboot temporarily resolves the problem.

What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Please note that for obvious reasons "WindowsFileServer" is not the actual name of the server just a variable I used to make it easier to read for this posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed 2 shares to use a guest account and the third I removed the space from the share name. Now things are working great. If I had to guess I'd say it was the space in the share name that caused the issues. My new /etc/fstab file looks like.

```
//WindowsFileServer/Media /mnt/Media cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0

//WindowsFileServer/Media2 /mnt/Media2 cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0

//WindowsFileServer/PlexOptimized /mnt/Optimized cifs credentials=/home/drew/.smbcreds,uid=108,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```